# wp ajax return 0

Tags: php, ajax

I know its full of questions about this on SO, and I have read most and applied all possible solutions, thus its still not working.

I have some ajax functions already up and working but for some reason this last one is not working.

I have simple ajax request which sends header to admin-ajax.php:

status is 200 (ok)

and header is:

`action:linked_post_image_grid`

the code in my php file is really basic for testing:

```
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_linked_post_image_grid', 'linked_post_image_grid');
add_action('wp_ajax_linked_post_image_grid', 'linked_post_image_grid');

function linked_post_image_grid(){

    echo 'this is return message';

    die();
}
```

now for some reason this only and always returns 0

Comment: Have you considered using a simple REST API endpoint instead?

Comment: Also if the others are working and this one is not, there should be _some_ difference comparing to the others. And the above code is not exactly enough to debug something like this. When you say `action:linked_post_image_grid` I hope you mean `action:'linked_post_image_grid'` edit: just realized I might not be understanding how your setup is... so ignore my ignorance on the action :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a simple alternative that sidesteps this issue entirely with a modern and easy to use interface, just use a REST API endpoint!

So lets turn this:

```
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_linked_post_image_grid', 'linked_post_image_grid');
add_action('wp_ajax_linked_post_image_grid', 'linked_post_image_grid');

function linked_post_image_grid(){

    echo 'this is return message';

    die();
}
```

Into this:

```
add_action( 'rest_api_init', function () {
        register_rest_route( 'buxbeatz/v1', '/linked_post_image_grid/', array(
                'methods' => 'GET',
                'callback' => 'linked_post_image_grid'
        ) );
} );

function linked_post_image_grid( $request ) {
    return "this is return message";
}
```

Now you can visit `example.com/wp-json/buxbeatz/v1/linked_post_image_grid` and you'll get a JSON response of `"this is return image"`

Comment: didnt think about REST api. Wil ltry to use it form now on. I actually get rest_no_route with your example

Comment: make sure you have rewrite rules turned on and that the code is somewhere it gets ran/loaded, aka in a plugin or `functions.php`, not inside a template

Comment: the rest api iteslf works going to localhost/sitename/wp-json works... the scripts are loaded in functions.php.
Its the custom endpoints created with the function that return 404

Comment: I can only suggest clearing caches and flushing permalinks, then checking that what you visit `/wp-json` that it lists the new endpoint in there

Comment: It's based off of an article I wrote [here](https://tomjn.com/2017/01/23/writing-wp-rest-api-endpoint-2-minutes/) which works fine on my site ( you can visit the endpoint in the article )

Comment: dont know why but placing the function in a new created file and re-requiring it in functions.php made it work. Thanks